# SQL: Creating quarter values based off conditional statements

Tags: sql, case

I have the following table:

| jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | jul | aug | sep | oct | nov | dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 322 |  |  |  |  | 44 |  |  |  |  | 1222 |  |

These are invoice amount columns. They're based off of the months of the year. What I'm trying to do is make a new column called execution window that will have different quarter values depending on where the amounts show up in the months. So basically:

Q1,
Q2,
Q3,
Q4,
Q1,Q2,
Q1, Q3, Q4,
Q2, Q3,
Q2, Q4

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work for every scenario:

```
   CASE
        WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1'
        
        WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2'
        
        WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q3'
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL OR forecast_november IS NOT NULL OR forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
            
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
                
                    WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q3'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q3'
            
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
            
                WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
                
                WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
                
                    WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
                    
                    WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
                    
                    WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL OR forecast_april IS NOT NULL OR forecast_may IS NOT NULL OR forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NULL AND forecast_august IS NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q2,Q4'
            
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
            
                    WHEN forecast_january IS NULL AND forecast_february IS NULL AND forecast_march IS NULL AND forecast_april IS NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL OR forecast_july IS NOT NULL OR forecast_august IS NOT NULL OR forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q3,Q4'
        
            
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
            
            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
            
                WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
                
                        WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
                        
                        WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
                        
                            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
                            
                            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NOT NULL AND forecast_june IS NOT NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q1,Q4'
                            ELSE NULL 
                            END AS new_execution_window
                            
                            
            WHEN forecast_january IS NOT NULL OR forecast_february IS NOT NULL OR forecast_march IS NOT NULL AND forecast_april IS NOT NULL AND forecast_may IS NULL AND forecast_june IS NULL AND forecast_july IS NOT NULL AND forecast_august IS NOT NULL AND forecast_september IS NOT NULL AND forecast_october IS NOT NULL AND forecast_november IS NOT NULL AND forecast_december IS NOT NULL THEN 'Q1,Q2,Q4'
```

Is there an easier way to pull this off? For example, if an amount shows up in January, June, or november, I would expect to see 'Q1, Q2, Q4' for that particular row. I'm trying to account for all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these amounts are always positive numbers, you can simply build the sum per quarter. Use `COALESCE` to avoid the sum will be `NULL` in case some columns have no amount:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
CASE WHEN COALESCE(jan,0) + COALESCE(feb,0) + COALESCE(mar,0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q1,' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(apr,0) + COALESCE(may,0) + COALESCE(jun,0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q2,' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(jul,0) + COALESCE(aug,0) + COALESCE(sep,0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q3,' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(oct,0) + COALESCE(nov,0) + COALESCE(dec,0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q4' ELSE '' END)
AS yourcolumn
FROM yourtable;
```

If the amounts can also be negative, furthermore use `ABS` to prevent the sum will be 0 for couples like 100,-100 etc.:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
CASE WHEN COALESCE(ABS(jan),0) + COALESCE(ABS(feb),0) + COALESCE(ABS(mar),0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q1,' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(ABS(apr),0) + COALESCE(ABS(may),0) + COALESCE(ABS(jun),0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q2,' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(ABS(jul),0) + COALESCE(ABS(aug),0) + COALESCE(ABS(sep),0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q3,' ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN COALESCE(ABS(oct),0) + COALESCE(ABS(nov),0) + COALESCE(ABS(dec),0) > 0 
  THEN 'Q4,' ELSE '' END)
AS yourcolumn
FROM yourtable;
```

Whenever the sum of amounts of a quarter is > 0, this means at least one of the months has an amount.

And this means you write that quarter to your result column.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l7BPma1Q)

Sidenote 1: Some DBMS don't provide this usage of `CONCAT`, you might need to replace that by the correct syntax of their string concatenation then.

Sidenote 2: The queries I've shown will of course produce results with a trailing comma after the last quarter which appeared if this quarter is not Q4. I guess you will be able to cut this off using your application or in SQL (the syntax for doing this in SQL depends on the DBMS again).

If you need assistance due to one or both of these two sidenotes, please tag your DBMS.

Comment: That would solve for having individual quarters. But what about for multiple quarters? Amounts can show up in different quarters. I could have an amount in January and an amount in December. That doesn’t mean it spans  Q1-Q4. It means it shows up in Q1 and Q4 only, not Q2 or Q3. How would I solve for cases like this?

Comment: In this case, the queries I've shown will return Q1,Q4. Try out ;)

Comment: Got it. You're right! I just got time to try out and it worked. My DBMS is Google Big Query. Not sure how to add that as a tag but I just need to figure out how to remove that trailing comma for the single quarters (i.e. 'Q2,', 'Q3,')

Comment: I don't use Google Big Query, but according to their documentation, RTRIM should do: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#rtrim

Comment: Yep, that would work. I was also thinking of just doing a CASE WHEN value is 'Q2,' THEN 'Q2' in a new temp table. That should work too as well as for the other use cases. Now I see why you wrapped all the CASE statements in a CONCAT. Always learn something about SQL every day. Thank you! You saved my butt.